# JS Datatable disappears when livewire starts a real time data save or update event on the input

Tags: laravel, datatables, laravel-livewire

I got an issue when I type in the input fields and save the data suddenly the js datatables disappear.

Image :

[IMAGE js datatables when normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JInPd.png)

[IMAGE js datatables when i type an input or save data suddenly disappeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyN0u.png)

**this is file : App\Http\Livewire\Suppliershow**

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Livewire;
    
    use App\Models\Supplier;
    use Livewire\Component;
    
    class SupplierShow extends Component
    {
        public $kd_supplier, $name, $address, $tlp, $email;
        public $suppliers;
    
        public function render()
        {
            $supplier = new Supplier();
            $this->kd_supplier =  $supplier->kd_supplier();
            $this->suppliers = Supplier::all();
            return view('livewire.supplier-show', [$this->suppliers]);
        }
    
        protected function rules()
        {
            return [
                'kd_supplier' => 'required',
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' =>  'email|nullable',
                'tlp' => 'digits_between:10,13|nullable'
            ];
        }
        protected $messages = [
            'name.required' => 'Bagian nama tidak boleh kosong.',
            'email.email' => 'Bagian email harus benar menggunakan format email @.',
            'tlp.digits_between' => 'Bagian no telp harus angka dan panjang antara 10 - 13 digit.',
        ];
        public function updated($propertyName)
        {
            $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
        }
    
        public function saveSupplier(){
            $this->validate();
            Supplier::create([
                'id_supplier' => $this->kd_supplier,
                'name' => $this->name,
                'address' => $this->address,
                'tlp' => $this->tlp,
                'email' => $this->email
            ]);
            $this->reset(['kd_supplier','name', 'address','tlp','email']);
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('close-modal');
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('swal');
     
    
        }
```

**this is file : resources\views\livewire\supplier-modal.blade.php**

```
{{-- CREATE MODAL SUPPLIER --}}
<div wire:ignore.self class="modal fade" id="suppliermodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="suppliermodalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="suppliermodalLabel">Form Tambah Supplier</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <form wire:submit.prevent='saveSupplier'>
        <div class="modal-body">
    
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Kode Supplier</label>
                <input type="text" wire:model="kd_supplier" readonly  class="form-control">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted"><i class="fa fa-info-circle text-success" aria-hidden="true"></i> Kode supplier otomatis</small>
                @error('kd_supplier')
                 <span class="error text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> 
                @enderror
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nama Supplier</label>
                <input type="text" wire:model="name" wire:model.defer class="@error('name') is-invalid @enderror form-control" placeholder="isi nama supplier">
                @error('name') 
                <span class="error text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> 
                @enderror
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Alamat</label>
                <input type="text" wire:model="address" class="@error('address') is-invalid @enderror form-control" placeholder="isi alamat">
                @error('address') 
                <span class="error text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> 
                @enderror
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <label>No Telp</label>
                <input type="text" wire:model="tlp" class="@error('tlp') is-invalid @enderror form-control" placeholder="cth. 081399990090">
                @error('tlp') 
                <span class="error text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> 
                @enderror
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" wire:model="email" class="@error('email') is-invalid @enderror form-control" placeholder="cth. joendoe@gmail.com">
                @error('email') 
                <span class="error text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> 
                @enderror
                </div>  
     
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">batal</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" wire:loading.attr='disabled' wire:target='saveSupplier'>
                    <span wire:loading.remove wire:target='saveSupplier'>simpan</span>
                    <div wire:loading wire:target='saveSupplier'>
                        <div class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status">
                        </div>
                        <span>proses...</span>
                    </div>
                  
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{-- END MODAL CREATE SUPPLIER --}}
```

**this is file : resources\views\livewire\supplier-show.blade.php**

```
<div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mb-3 float-end" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#suppliermodal"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Tambah Supplier</button>
    </div>
    @include('livewire.supplier-modal')
    <div>
    <table   id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No</th>
          <th>Kode</th>
          <th>Nama</th>
          <th>Alamat</th>
          <th>Tlp</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Aksi</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($suppliers as $supplier)
        <tr>
          <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
          <td>{{ $supplier->id_supplier }}</td>
          <td>{{ $supplier->name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $supplier->address }}</td>
          <td>{{ $supplier->tlp }}</td>
          <td>{{ $supplier->email }}</td>    
          <td><a href="" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> |
            <form action="" method="post" class="d-inline">
              @method('delete')
              @csrf
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Apakah anda yakin ?')"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              </form>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
  
        </tbody>
       
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```